# How to find the period of $ (\tan x )^{0.45}$?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

How to find the period of $(\tan x)^{0.45}$?

I know the period of $\tan x$ is $\pi$.  Can anyone please help me?

Comment: $\tan(x^{0.45})$ or $(\tan x)^{0.45}$?

Comment: I have edited.@Lord

Comment: What is $(-1)^{0.45}$?

Comment: Consider the domain where the function is valid.

Comment: Question has come in this form

Comment: Come from where?

Comment: I got this question in my analysis book. This book is not popular. You will not know it. I  made only one change. There was 0.5 in the place 0.45.

Answer (score 3):

$\pi$. You do not change periodicity by raising to this particular power.
Obviously $(\tan(x+\pi))^{0.45}= (\tan(x))^{0.45}$. So all you need to check if there is not a shorter period. But where $\tan$ is positive, so your function is defined, the function is increasing in each smaller than $\pi$ interval, so it cannot have smaller periodicity.

Comment: Thank you for your sweet cute answer. Can you plz explain@Andrei

Comment: I've modified my answer. For the case of $\sin^2 x$ the sine function is not always increasing, so by squaring it you can make the period half. But for any monotonic function you cannot change the period.

Comment: Can you tell me what will happen when the function is not monotonic in the period. Like $(sinx)^0.5$?@Andrei

Comment: You need an even integer power in order to modify the period, by changing all negatives to positives. Otherwise, raising any function to a power will not change periodicity.

Comment: Then how did it happen for this question? @Andrei

Comment: It did not change periodicity

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the period is indeed $\pi$:

[image]

The base function need not be monotonic.  In general, if $f(x)$ has period $T$, then $g(f(x))$ will also have period $T$.

Comment: Can you tell what will happen when the function is not monotonic in the period. Like $(sinx)^0.5$?@David G. Stork

Answer (score 1):

Given a periodic function $f$ with smallest period $p$ and an injective function $g$.  The composition $g\circ f$ is a function with potentially smaller domain, but if that domain is nonempty, then $g\circ f$ is still periodic with smallest period $p$.

First of all, $p$ is clearly a period to $g\circ f$. 
Secondly, $g\circ f$ cannot have a smaller period. 
That would mean that there are two numbers in the new domain, $x,y$, whose distance is less than $p$ and $g(f(x))= g(f(y))$. 
But as the function $g$ is injective, this implies $f(x)=f(y)$, a contradiction.

As $x\mapsto x^{0.45}$ is injective, the period is $\pi$.

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, look at $\sin^2 x$. Your assumption that $x^r$ is one to one is not true for $x^2$.

Comment: Good point (I haven't read the other comments). Thank you! I am going to rephrase my answer.